# Determining Buck Converter's source voltage average value from current waveform

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, buck

[image]

Dear all,

Given that the above is the instantaneous source current drawn by a **buck converter**, may I know how I should go about determining the corresponding average value of the source voltage?

Edit:
Here's what I have attempted or understand could lead to a solution.
**1)** The gradient of the positive slope in the current waveform equals to the source voltage over inductance value. However, the inductance value is not given.
**2)** I could calculate the duty cycle of the converter using the on and off period. And possibly find source voltage if I have the output voltage but the output voltage is not given either.

Comment: Homework question without any attempt at solving?

Comment: Definitely sounds like homework without an attempt at solution.  What have you tried, and where are you stuck?  Your question will be closed unless you can show some effort in answering the question.  Start with V=L*di/dt.

Comment: You can even calculate the output voltage too. So what have you tried to formulate so far?

Comment: Knowing the current is really cool, but it says absolutely nothing about the voltage, so there is no answer...

Comment: @peufeu The waveform as a whole tells you quite a bit about the voltage.  If you know the value of L it's almost trivial to calculate Vin and Vout.

Comment: @JohnD True! How could I miss that. Knowing L and di/dt will give Vin-Vout, so you'd still need to know Vout to know Vin though...

Comment: @peufeu Vout is even easier to get-  It's not shown but by looking at the diagram you know what the downslope of the inductor current must be during the off time.  That with L gives you the output voltage.  Now the OP should have plenty of hints to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments. I omitted typing my attempt for the very reason that I was stuck at the very first step. I'm aware that the gradient of the rising slope of the current waveform equates to source voltage over inductance. However, there was no inductance value given, thus I thought I may be heading off onto a totally wrong approach..

Comment: @JohnD Have added in my solution attempts kind sir.

Comment: Did they provide a circuit diagram?

Comment: @MathieuK. The waveform above is all that is given, being stated that it is the instantaneous source current drawn by a buck converter. Unfortunately no other parameters were given, hence my being stuck.

Comment: "1) The gradient of the positive slope in the current waveform equals to the source voltage over inductance value. However, the inductance value is not given."  Not exactly.  When the switch is on, you have Vin-Vout impressed across the inductor, and the slope is that voltage over the inductance.  You also have the duty cycle, and the fact that the inductor current is continuous.  This gives you Vo/Vin.  So you can write Vin as a function of L at the very least.

Comment: @JohnD damn, my brain was really offline yesterday! I had a rather... ehrmmm, busy saturday night. Sorry about that.

Comment: @peufeu No worries, been there too.  Though I think you were right that you can't tell the input voltage without knowing the value of L.  If you keep the ratio of Vin/Vout you will get the same result for the current wavefork by doubling the voltage and the inductance.  So you need L to get Vin.  I think the best the OP can do is write Vin as a function of L.